# How to increase Length of a ComboBox item in MFC

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have created a Dialog application using MFC. I have an `CComboBox` in it, I am able to enter an URL of Length 60 characters. But when the length increases , I am unable to enter.

Comment: `CBS_AUTOHSCROLL` allows to enter more characters in to combobox (simple or dropdown style). You can set this flag in dialog resources (set "Auto" flag = true). Note, there is no effect if you modify this flag after combobox creation.

Comment: If it's created dynamically, you can do this, `m_combobox.create(|CBS_AUTOHSCROLL)`    

If static, select  `AUTOHSCROLL`  when editing resources

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Why not convert your comment into an answer so that it is indicated the question has been answered?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle yes you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CBS_AUTOHSCROLL` allows adding more characters in to combobox's edit control (simple or dropdown style).

You can set this flag when combobox is created. However there is no effect if you modify this flag after combobox creation.

In dialog resource editor, this flag appears as "Auto" in comboxbox properties.

[Combo Box Styles:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/combo-box-styles)

> `CBS_AUTOHSCROLL`
>
> Automatically scrolls the text in an edit control to the right when
>   the user types a character at the end of the line. If this style is
>   not set, only text that fits within the rectangular boundary is
>   allowed.